# SoapUI on linux (wayland) - high DPI/4K scaling issue

Tags: soapui

SoapUI doesn't seem to be DPI-Aware and displays too small on my high DPI screen (tiny text and buttons). Other applications are running fine (screen resolution 3840 x 2160).

[image]

Some information:
- Arch linux running wayland
- Installed soapUI via there website

I have tried:
- In the launch script add `-Dsun.java2d.ddscale=true` to `JAVA_OPTS` but it doesn't seem to have any effects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2` to JAVA_OPTS (in soapui.sh) worked for me. It seems that only integer values are working (1.5 does nothing, for instance).

Comment: This didn't work for me with SoapUI-5.7.0, I had to add it to SoapUI-5.7.0.vmoptions.

Comment: this helps with multiscreen ```res=$(xdpyinfo | awk '/dimensions/{print $2}')

if [ "$res" = "3840x1200" ]; then
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1"
else
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

If you install soapui in the directory by default, go to $HOME/SmartBear/SoapUI-5.6.0/bin and edit the file SoapUI-5.6.0 (vim, nano, etc), go to the end of the file and find:

$INSTALL4J_JAVA_PREFIX exec "$app_java_home/bin/java" "-splash:$app_home/.install4j/s_12opuop.png" -Dinstall4j.jvmDir="$app_java_home" -Dexe4j.moduleName="$prg_dir/$progname" "-Dinstall4j.launcherId=64" "-Dinstall4j.swt=false" "$vmov_1" "$vmov_2" "$vmov_3" "$vmov_4" "$vmov_5" $INSTALL4J_ADD_VM_PARAMS -classpath "$local_classpath" com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher launch a0622774 "$prg_dir/error.log" 0 com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI  "$@"
return_code=$?

Where you have to insert with quotes "-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2"

$INSTALL4J_JAVA_PREFIX exec "$app_java_home/bin/java" "-splash:$app_home/.install4j/s_12opuop.png" -Dinstall4j.jvmDir="$app_java_home" -Dexe4j.moduleName="$prg_dir/$progname" "-Dinstall4j.launcherId=64" "-Dinstall4j.swt=false" "-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2" "$vmov_1" "$vmov_2" "$vmov_3" "$vmov_4" "$vmov_5" $INSTALL4J_ADD_VM_PARAMS -classpath "$local_classpath" com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher launch a0622774 "$prg_dir/error.log" 0 com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI  "$@"
return_code=$?

I tried this in a Majaro 20.2.1 with XFCE and works fine.

Answer (score 4):

For me I got it working in SoapUI-5.6.0 by adding `-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2` as a new line to the file `~/SmartBear/SoapUI-5.6.0/bin/SoapUI-5.6.0.vmoptions`.

I tried the previous answer about editing `soapui.sh` but I didn't have luck with that myself.

Comment: Also works in SoapUI-5.7.0, thank you!